# How to access contacts of logged-in google user account while building google Action

Tags: java, spring-boot, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

1. I am creating an action on google and need message to a contact exists in the contact list of user(logged-in by google).
2. I am developing this action using Dialog flow, and its fulfilment using **Spring-boot** & **java**.

We can send message by asking user to speak out the contact number but it is not feasible to remember one's number.
How can I access the contacts & use them?

Comment: No , in that the user is asking to use only account details which include email, name etc but not contacts.

Comment: Have you tried using either the People API (https://developers.google.com/people/) or the Contacts API (https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/)?